# Running multiple instances of an SSIS package via SQLAgent concurrently

Tags: ssis, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have an SSIS Package scheduled to run every X minutes in SQLAgent that subsequenly executes a plethora of child packages if certain conditions are met.  The problem I am having is that sometimes some of the child packages take a lot longer than X minutes to run which in turn means that nothing else can run until all child packages complete.

This also means that during that run time the conditions to run a child package may have come and went which would mean that they do not run, even when the original package completes.

Is there a way to allow concurrent instances of a parent package to run even if it is previously running?

ParentA is scheduled to run every 10 minutes, at 10:00 it kicks off and ChildA's criteria is met.  ChildB needs to run at 10:20am, it is not met so it does not run.  ChildA takes 3 hours to complete.

I need to have a new instance of ParentA kick off at 10:10 and then again at 10:20.

How can I go about doing this without having 2+ ParentA scheduled and having to do some fancy coding so multiple instances of the child packages aren't kicked off?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would change the ParentA package so that it starts once and does not terminate, but has a series of loops that launch Child packages.

Within PackageA I would add a For Loop Container, within that I would add an Execute SQL Task that uses SQL WAITFOR command to pause for 10 minutes.  Then I would run ChildA package.

I would repeat that pattern for ChildB etc.  As each For Loop Container is independant, they will loop independantly.  Each individual Loop Container will wait for it's Child package to complete before looping.

You need to add some mechanism to stop the looping, e.g. check on the system time, count the number of loops or similar.  This test would go in each For Loop's EvalExpression property.

Comment: Won't that cause issues if one of the child packages fails?  Wouldn't the whole loop fail and then the parent package would have to be restarted?

Comment: That seems like a separate consideration from your original question, but anyway you can configure an SSIS package to continue if errors occur.  You could also configure the job that launches ParentA package to run on a recurring schedule e.g. every 10 minutes. This wont have any effect until ParentA terminates for whatever reason.